# Can a commander sent to the graveyard be brought back by a sorcery or instant card or ability without costing mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Can a commander sent to the graveyard be brought back by a sorcery or instant card or ability without costing mana?

I know I can put it in the command-zone. But does that mean I can get it back out of the "graveyard" with an ability?

Comment: At the moment, this is too vague for us to answer. Could you please add references to _exactly_ which spells and/or abilities you are referring to?

Answer (score 3):

The command zone and graveyard are different zones of the game. A spell or ability which targets a card in a graveyard can't target your Commander if your commander is in the command zone.

If you commander dies, you as its owner may choose whether to send it to the command zone or leave it in the graveyard:

> 903.9a If a commander is in a graveyard or in exile and that object was put into that zone since the last time state-based actions were checked, its owner may put it into the command zone. This is a state-based action. See rule 704.

If you choose to leave it in the graveyard, it would be a legal target for a spell such as [Reanimate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reanimate). You wouldn't need to pay the 'commander tax' in addition, as you're not casting your commander from the command zone.